# How to show data from database depending on user's choice from a select

Tags: php, jquery, database, select

I have to make a select and when user choose option from it, it should be displayed data from database based on this select. I can't use submit. It only should be displayed this select and when option is selected, to show data from this select. I'm new to jQuery and I can't do it. My view is:

```
 <select name="myselect" id="myselect" >

        <option value=''" . set_select('size, '') . " > </option>

        <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('size', '1'); ?> role="menuitem">1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php echo set_select('size', '2'); ?> role="menuitem">2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php echo set_select('size', '3'); ?> role="menuitem">3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php echo set_select('size', '4'); ?> role="menuitem">4</option>
 </select>
```

My model is:

```php
<?php

    public function average_price_by_week() {

            $this->db->select(*);
            $this->db->from('items');

            $this->db->where('size', $size); //this $size should be value from select that user has selected

            $query=$this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();

        }



?>
```

Comment: use ajax to solve this. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this, It may help you.

I have used `JQuery Ajax`. Also include `JQuery library` before use the below code.

```
$('#myselect').change(function(){
    var size = $('#myselect').val();
    if(size != ''){
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:"/index.php/average_incomes_by_customer/" + size,
            cache:false,
            success: function(returndata){
                console.log(returndata); //"returndata" is the result got from the DB. Use it where you want.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public function average_incomes_by_customer($size) { 
    $data['average_price']=$this->receivedOrders_model->average_price_by_week($size);
    $this->load->view('charts', $data); 
}
```

Model:

```
public function average_price_by_week($size) {
    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('size', $size); //this $size should be value from select that user has selected           
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How to change returned data from database - should I use Get ot post? I mean in my model:$this->db->where('size', $size); how to pass it this value from ajax? Thanks. My controller is:  public function average_incomes_by_customer()
 {             $data['average_price']=$this->receivedOrders_model->average_price_by_week();
        $this->load->view('charts', $data);
 }

Comment: Are you using any framework?. you can use either `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter.

Comment: I tried in my controller method:  $Size = $this->uri->segment(3);$data['average_price']=$this->receivedOrders_model->average_price_by_week($Size); But data isn't changed.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: Link is shown :  
http://localhost:9080/myfprojectfolder/index.php/average_incomes_by_customer/1 But 404 not found. It is shown as $this->uri->segment(3) - get . How to get this value? If I put in controller: $size = $this->uri->segment(3);   How should be changed ajax to be with get?

Comment: I don't know in detail about how to call the controller action in URL. Check in google about giving url in `ajax` on `codeignitor`

Comment: Use `type: 'GET'` instead of `type: 'POST'`

Comment: I haven't been put my method name in link. Now it is: http://localhost/myprojectfolder/index.php/receivedOrders/ average_incomes_by_customer/1 . In controller I have:  public function average_incomes_by_customer()
 {
        $size = $this->uri->segment(3);$data['average_price']=$this->receivedOrders_model->average_price_by_week($size); $this->load->view('charts', $data);
 } But nothing is displayed. How to put my data - it is data for a chart. Chart's data should be changed. How to put data from result in chart?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80160/discussion-between-siva-g-and-ci-lover).